# jQuery validate only by remote

Tags: jquery

My form has 4 fields and at least one of them must contain a number. I can handle this all by remote but I can't get the snippet below to call the remote function unless I also add a `required: true` to the rules. `codes[25]` is just one of the fields.

```
$("#create-codes-form").validate({
        rules: {
            'codes[25]': {
                remote: {
                    url: site_url+"codes/validate",
                    async: false,
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        codes: function() {
                            return $("#create-codes-form").serialize();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Why, when I submit this form, is the remote call not being made?

EDIT: the remote call is being made if I enter a value in the codes[25] field, but not if I submit the form without touching any of the fields.

Comment: It works for me here, open the console and you'll see it sends the request: http://jsfiddle.net/8NkEN/

Comment: Sorry I don't see any remote calls in Console or Network

Comment: If I remove your "required" from the input field I do see a response of "{"error": "Please use POST request"}" but I don't see any remote calls being made.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize I left the `required` attribute in there, my copy/paste mistake. At least you can use the demo for debugging. looked at it real quick and yeah it's not sending the request when I type in the field and submit.

Answer (score 0):

it mean there is any problem in url cold you show what you are returning

and write the data like below there is no need of function

```
 data: { codes:  $("#create-codes-form").serialize() }
```

Comment: @stef hey it that answer helpful or was helful to you ? Else I delete it